# I have created a python application using pyinstaller on windows 10 64bit system. But it only opens gui and doesn't work on other windows 10 64 bit?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

It was supposed to overlay one image over other and open that image but it's not working why can it be??
**The real problem is that It works on some systems but not on others.**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/13DDMR1riSYgGqzh0PQscN6Zo-xlcJEPT/view?usp=sharing
link of video showing how it opens the gui but doesn't work further.
Code for GUI
The GUI isn't good and the code may not be tidy but I am starting to code just now and I don't know much. It will be great if you could help debug it.

```
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import overlay
import sqlite3
import sys
import os
from scrollableimg import ScrollableImage as scimg

data = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
c = data.cursor()


tables = c.execute("""
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table';""").fetchall()
if len(tables) == 0:
    c.execute("""CREATE TABLE position (x integer, y integer);""")
    c.execute("""CREATE TABLE size (x integer, y integer);""")

data.commit()


root = Tk()


width= root.winfo_screenwidth()
height= root.winfo_screenheight()

#setting tkinter window size
root.geometry("%dx%d" % (width, height))

root.title('settings')

path = os.getcwd()


data.commit()


def click(event):

   input_position.configure(state=NORMAL)
   input_position.delete(0, END)
   input_position.unbind('<Button-1>', positions)

def click1(event):
   input_size.configure(state=NORMAL)
   input_size.delete(0, END)
   input_size.unbind('<Button-1>', sizes)


def change_position_size(path, position, size):
    '''To change the position and size of qr code'''
    overlay.remove(path)
    if type(position) == tuple and type(size) == tuple:
        overlay.overlay_img(path, position, size)
        os.chdir(path)
        for items in os.listdir():
            if items.lower().endswith('.jpg') and items.lower().startswith('inv') and not items.lower().startswith('invoice') and not items.lower().startswith('invoicev'):
                image = Image.open(path + '/' + items)
                img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=image)
    
        label = scimg(root, image = img1, scrollbarwidth = 9, width = width/1.0125, height = height/1.01)
        label.grid(row = 4, column = 0, columnspan = 4)
        

        #Delete present data from table
        c.execute("DELETE FROM position")
        c.execute("DELETE FROM size")

        #insert new data
        c.execute("INSERT INTO position (x, y) VALUES (?, ?)", (position[0], position[1]))
        c.execute("INSERT INTO size (x, y) VALUES (?, ?)", (size[0], size[1]))

        data.commit()
    else:
        label = Label(root, text = '!!!Enter position and size in 200, 198 format!!!', font = ('Arial', 13), foreground = 'red')
        label.grid(row = 3, column = 0, columnspan = 2)

def test_input(position, size):
    '''To check the correctness of input'''
    position = position.split(', ')
    size = size.split(', ')
    new_position = []
    new_size = []

    if len(position) == 2 and len(size) == 2:
        for x in position:
            for y in x:
                if not y in ('0123456789'):
                    print(sys.path)
                    raise ValueError('Enter numbers only')
            new_position.append(int(x))
        position = tuple(new_position)        
        for x in size:
            for y in x:
                if not y in ('0123456789'):
                    print(sys.path)
                    raise ValueError('Enter numbers only')
            new_size.append(int(x))  
        size = tuple(new_size)
    else:
        print('position and size in 0, 0 format')
    change_position_size(path, position, size)


#getting data from the database

position = c.execute("SELECT * FROM position").fetchall()
size = c.execute("SELECT * FROM size").fetchall()


input_position = Entry(root, width = 20, borderwidth = 5, font  = ('Arial', 20))
input_position.grid( row = 1, column = 0, sticky = 'n')

if len(position) != 0:
    input_position.insert(0, (str(position[0][0]) + ', ' + str(position[0][1])))
else:
    input_position.insert(0, '0, 0')
positions = input_position.bind('<Button-1>', click)
text = Label(root, pady = 6, text = 'Please Enter The position For QR Code in 200, 198 format here and press enter         ', font = ('Arial', 13))
text.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

input_size = Entry(root, width = 20, borderwidth = 5, font  = ('Arial', 20))
input_size.grid(row= 1, column = 1)


if len(size) != 0:
    input_size.insert(0, (str(size[0][0]) +', ' +  str(size[0][1])))
else:
    input_size.insert(0, '200, 200')
sizes = input_size.bind('<Button-1>', click1)

text1 = Label(root, pady = 6, text = 'Please Enter The Size For QR Code in 200, 198 format here and press enter ', font = ('Arial', 13))
text1.grid(row = 0, column = 1)



Enter = Button(root, text = 'Enter', height = 3, width = 10, command  =lambda: test_input(input_position.get(), input_size.get()))
Enter.grid(row= 0, column = 2, pady = (12, 2), rowspan = 2)

root.bind('<Return>', lambda event=None: Enter.invoke())


root.mainloop()



data.close()
```

Code for Overlay which is imported in GUI used to overlay one image over other.

```
import os
import sqlite3
import string



def create_proper_img(path):
    for items in os.listdir():
        if 'invoice.jpg' == items.lower():
            image = Image.open(path + '/' + items)
        else:
            if 'invoicev.jpg' == items.lower():
                image3 = Image.open(path + '/' + items)
                break

    return image, image3

def resize_qr(path, size):
    for items in os.listdir():
        if items.lower().endswith('.gif') and items.lower().startswith('qr'): 
            with Image.open(path + '/' + items).convert('RGBA') as image1:
                qr_image = image1.copy()
                resized_qr = qr_image.resize((size), Image.Resampling.HAMMING)
                break
    return resized_qr

def overlay_img(path, position, size):
    os.chdir(path)
    for items in os.listdir():
        if items.lower().endswith('.gif') and items.lower().startswith('qr'):
            x = items.strip(string.ascii_letters + string.punctuation + string.whitespace)
            break
    list = os.listdir()
    if 'INVOICE.jpg' in list and 'INVOICEV.jpg' in list and not "INV{x}.jpg".format(x = x) in list and type(position) == tuple and type(size) == tuple:
        images = create_proper_img(path)
        image = images[0]
        image1 = images[1]
        resized_qr = resize_qr(path, size)
        copied_image = image.copy()
        copied_image1 = image1.copy()
        copied_image.paste(resized_qr, position, resized_qr)
        copied_image1.paste(resized_qr, position, resized_qr)
        copied_image1 = copied_image1.convert('RGB')
        copied_image = copied_image.convert('RGB')   
        copied_image.save(path + '/INV' + x + '.jpg', dpi = image.info['dpi'])
        copied_image1.save(path + '/INP' + x + '.jpg', dpi = image.info['dpi'])

def remove(path):
    for item in os.listdir():
        if not item.startswith('INVOICE') and not item.startswith('INVOICEV') and item.startswith('INV') and item.endswith('jpg'):
            os.remove(item)

def main(path, position, size):
    
    overlay_img(path, position, size)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = os.getcwd()
    os.chdir(path)
    data = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
    c = data.cursor()
    position = c.execute("SELECT * FROM position").fetchall()
    size = c.execute("SELECT * FROM size").fetchall()

    main(path, position[0], size[0])
    data.close()
```

for scrollbars

````
class ScrollableImage(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kw):
        self.image = kw.pop('image', None)
        sw = kw.pop('scrollbarwidth', 10)
        super(ScrollableImage, self).__init__(master=master, **kw)
        self.cnvs = tkinter.Canvas(self, highlightthickness=0, **kw)
        self.cnvs.create_image(0, 0, anchor='nw', image=self.image)
        # Vertical and Horizontal scrollbars
        self.v_scroll = tkinter.Scrollbar(self, orient='vertical', width=sw)
        self.h_scroll = tkinter.Scrollbar(self, orient='horizontal', width=sw)
        # Grid and configure weight.
        self.cnvs.grid(row=0, column=0,  sticky='nsew')
        self.h_scroll.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ew')
        self.v_scroll.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        # Set the scrollbars to the canvas
        self.cnvs.config(xscrollcommand=self.h_scroll.set, 
                           yscrollcommand=self.v_scroll.set)
        # Set canvas view to the scrollbars
        self.v_scroll.config(command=self.cnvs.yview)
        self.h_scroll.config(command=self.cnvs.xview)
        # Assign the region to be scrolled 
        self.cnvs.config(scrollregion=self.cnvs.bbox('all'))
        self.cnvs.bind_class(self.cnvs, "<MouseWheel>", self.mouse_scroll)

    def mouse_scroll(self, evt):
        shift = (evt.state & 0x1) != 0
        scroll = -1 if evt.delta > 0 else 1
        if shift:
            self.cnvs.xview_scroll(scroll, "units")
        else:
            self.cnvs.yview_scroll(scroll, "units")```
````

Comment: could you show us the code? put is as text formatted as code. Did it work when you ran the source code without pyinstaller?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Yes it works on some systems but doesn't work on other systems.
It is a file created in 64 bit so it will only work on 64 bit system. I will include linkto files  here [https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1AHYpZuzpbRqgW9TX4eZx9yU0dVaQo0qw?usp=sharing].

Comment: we still cannot see your code. You need to put your code in the question, properly formatted

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I have added the code now could you check it please. I am just starting to code so I don't know much. I am just trying to solve this error.

Comment: your code tried to connect to a database, but you don't handle the case where the connection fails. You should add logging for each step you do that might fail. Then once you execute the exe look at the log nd it will tell you were it fail. Most likely the database connection cannot be stablished

Comment: You should also not name your variables "list" or any other reserved keyworks. Naming a variable list will cause a lot of errors. for example if you try to later convert some data to a list and you do `list(someData)` it will complain since now list is no longer a list constructor but a variable.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki thank you very much. I was just making the program non consoled so I couldn't see the errors. Now that I log the errors the problem was in the naming convention. Thank you for your help. Really appreciate it.